# How do I merge the master repo's changes to my own?

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm new to Github and I am modifying an existing WP plugin. I forked the "master" branch into what I believe can now be called *my* repo. That all seemed fine.

I was making changes to the files on notepad++ but now the author has released some changes.

1. Is it possible to upload the entire plugin to my repo?
2. After that, can I merge the author's changes into mine without deleting all the changes I made?

Comment: You could add a new remote, call it "source" or something, and fetch from it, then merge or rebase the changes into your branch. `git add origin source git@github.com:vendor/package.git` then `git fetch source` then `git rebase source/master`

Comment: @RobbieAverill that all assumes I have Git for Windows set up right?

Comment: Yeah. Not sure how you'd do it without it

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ check this out

Comment: @RobbieAverill I thought it might be possible to just upload the files using the github website and then hopefully there was a way to merge directly on the github website as well.

Comment: @RobbieAverill where you wrote `git@github.com:vendor/package.git` would I replace that with the link to the plugin's github page and then also include the name of the branch? Would it be `git@github.com/anspress/anspress/master.git` or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, neither of which will guarantee that you won't have conflicts:

1) Run a `git stash` to save your changes. Then checkout out `master` and pull so you get the other developer's changes. Go back to your feature branch `git rebase master` and then `git stash pop` to reapply your changes on top of the other developer's work. Resolve any conflicts and continue.

2) The other option is pretty much the same but rather than stashing your changes you commit your work before rebasing with master. It depends really on the nature of the work, whether you need to make use of the other developer's changes on which option you go for. If your changes are pretty isolated then the latter option may be preferred.

You can merge master into your feature branch but this isn't as "nice" an option. You can see the difference between the two here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Comment: Well, conflicts are just where my code differs from the author's, so those are the areas where I might have made a change. If it points me to conflict areas, I can always just select the code that looks like mine, no?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the your change and your colleague's, he may have made a change that you want to keep, and you may want to keep yours also. The first example that pops into my head is say you both add a new parameter to a method.

Comment: I tend to use the command line for git, and resolve conflicts within the IDE.

Comment: I've been trying this all for a few days but I'm somewhat slow at learning Git....Could I bother you for just a sec? I'm attempting your answer using 2 folders (repos) on my local machine. They are called FolderMaster and FolderLocal. I put 2 files in each one titled "anspress". I then made some changes to the file in FolderLocal on a feature branch. Then I did a checkout on master and pulled from FolderMaster. But I get an error: http://imgur.com/TKwoPwA

Comment: That's normal, you need to go into that file and fix it, it's basically telling you git doesn't know what to do with it as there are changes that conflict with one another. Once you've fixed it:

`git add C:\Users\aaron\Desktop\FDMain\Anspress-Github-DL\anspress.txt`
 
`git commit`